# create class for point coordinates

Tags: c++, overloading

i have following  class with overloading operators

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class Cvector
{
public:
    int x,y;
    Cvector() {  x=0;y=0;}
    Cvector(int,int);
    Cvector operator+(Cvector);
    Cvector operator-(Cvector);
    int  operator*(Cvector);
    bool operator==(Cvector);
    Cvector operator*(int);
    Cvector operator=(Cvector);

    int cross_multiplication(Cvector,Cvector);
    float  norm();

    };
Cvector Cvector::operator=(Cvector a)
{
    x=a.x;
    y=a.y;
    return *this;

}
bool Cvector::operator==(Cvector b)
{
    return (x==b.x && y==b.y);

}

Cvector Cvector::operator*(int c)
{
    Cvector temp;
    temp.x=c*x;
    temp.y=c*y;
    return temp;

}
float Cvector::norm()
{
    float result=0;
    result+=x*x+y*y;;
    return sqrt(result);


}
Cvector::Cvector(int a,int b)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;

}
Cvector Cvector::operator+(Cvector a)
{
    Cvector temp;
    temp.x=x+a.x;
    temp.y=y+a.y;
    return temp;

}
Cvector Cvector::operator-(Cvector b)
{
    Cvector temp;
    temp.x=x-b.x;
    temp.y=y-b.y;
    return temp;

}
int Cvector::operator*(Cvector a)
{
    return x*a.x+y*a.y;


}

int main()
{
    Cvector a(3,4);
    Cvector b(4,5);
    cout<<b.norm()<<endl;
    Cvector c;
    c=a*b;
    cout<<(a==b)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me one error

```
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point_class\point_class\point_class.cpp(86): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point_class\point_class\point_class.cpp(16): could be 'Cvector Cvector::operator =(Cvector)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Cvector, int)'
```

please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Root Cause:**

```
int Cvector::operator*(Cvector a)
```

returns an `int`, so:

```
c=a*b;
```

tries to assign an `int` to a `Cvector` object, which needs a overloaded `=` operator of `Cvector` class to take `int` as parameter, which it doesn't. Hence the error.

> **Suggested Solution:**

`c` has no business being a `Cvector`, it should be an `int` ideally, so either it could be a typo or it could indeed be the intent(*which does break conventional algebraic wisdon*).I am not sure which one it is.

If it is the former, just change type of `c` to `int`.

If it is latter, You need to provide a constructor which takes in an `int` parameter:

```
Cvector::Cvector(int)
{

}
```

This constructor will implicitly called to convert the `int` result of `operator *` and convert it to an `Cvector` object which will then be used to call the `operator =`.

**[Online Demo of your code with suggested solution](http://ideone.com/sNpVR)**

Comment: I'm not sure that introducing an arbitrary conversion from a scalar to a vector is the best way to fix the choice of the wrong type to represent a scalar. That will cause many other logic errors to go uncaught by the compiler.

Comment: The suggested solution doesn't make sense mathematically. OP is defining the operation as the scalar product, which should not be convertible to a non-scalar.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That would depend on OPs intent.

Comment: @Als agreed, if OP intends to subvert the laws of vector algebra, then yes :-)

Comment: @Als: Presumably the intent is to represent a mathematical vector. Mathematically, there's no natural map between a vector space and its underlying field (except in the trivial case of a one-dimensional space), so there's no sensible way to define such a conversion. Choosing some arbitrary conversion will just prevent you from using the type system to catch category errors like this one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: In that case `c` has no business being a `Cvector` but still it is, so either it could be a typo or it could indeed be the intent.I am not sure which one it is.

Comment: @Als: Indeed: the bug is that `c` should be a scalar type, since it's being used to store the result of a scalar product. Hiding the bug by allowing a nonsensical type conversion won't fix anything.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Sure, I will add that as an note but again OP is the best person to comment.

Comment: yes @Als c shoud be scalar and this is what i have changed too,i  have  not concentrated deeply about multiplication type,it is why i have made this mistake

Comment: @dato I added a comment about this in my answer. It might make sense to use member functions rather than operators for the vector multiplications, since there are at least two valid operations, returning different types.

Comment: @juanchopanza  unfortunately i could  not give you another +1,thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Your multiplication operator `int Cvector::operator*(Cvector a)` returns `int`. Then you try to assign this `int` to `Cvector c`. There is no such assignment operator in your class that allows `int` to be converted into `Cvector`.

To resolve this you need to return `Cvector` from `Cvector::operator*` (like in `operator+`) or define assignment operator that gets `int` as input parameter (doesn't make a lot of sense for me, but...)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
int Cvector::operator*(Cvector a)
{
    return x*a.x+y*a.y;
}
```

You are retunring an int from this multiplication, which you attempt to assign to a `Cvector` here:

```
c=a*b;
```

The solution here is to assign to an integer:

```
int dotProd = a*b;
```

Since there are at least two meaningful vector multiplication operations (scalar and vector product), it would probably make sense to remove the operator altogether and add specific `dot(const Cvector&)` and a `cross(const Cvector&)` methods.

There are also some oddities in your code. For example, here:

```
Cvector Cvector::operator+(Cvector a)
{
    Cvector temp;
    temp.x=x+a.x;
    temp.y=y+a.y;
    return temp;
}
```

you take a `Cvector` by value, so there is no need for the `temp` copy. You can operate directly on `a` and return it.

Comment: Nitpick: `cross` should also return `int`; the three-dimensional cross-product of two 2-vectors is orthogonal to the plane of those vectors, so can't be represented as a 2-vector. The best representation is a scalar, giving the orthogonal component (the other components being zero). But +1 anyway, a more descriptive answer than mine.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks, it has been years since I had to think about this kind of stuff!